# How to stop ajax timer if results contains key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function crunchifyAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/user/show-user-task-messages?code=<c:out value="${liveCode}"/>',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(crunchifyAjax, 100);
</script>
```

The function check every 100ms my url and return some text like this:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
stop
```

I want to break this timer after `data` contains **stop**. How can I do this?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function crunchifyAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/user/show-user-task-messages?code=<c:out value="${liveCode}"/>',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                if((""+data).indexOf("stop") > -1)
                    clearInterval(intervalId); //clearing the interval started by setInterval
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(crunchifyAjax, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: `stop` is undefined

Comment: sorry @The_ehT...! thanks for pointing out this mistake...`:)`!

Comment: Work nice. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server returns an array of items like

```
["1","2","4","stop","6"]
```

You can check the array coming back and see whether it has an item "`stop`" and if yes call `clearInterval` method.

```
success: function (data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
          var subset = data.filter(function (a) {
                    return a === "stop";
          });
          if (subset.length > 0) {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
         }
}
```

If your server is returning a string like `"1,3,5,stop,6"`, you can do `indexOf` method to check the existence of the specific string

```
success: function(data) {
           $('#result').html(data);
           if (data.indexOf("stop") > -1) {
                window.clearInterval(intervalId);
           }
```

*If you are returning a collection of items, I strongly suggest you to return an array instead of a concatenated string.*

Comment: I am getting : `Uncaught TypeError: data.filter is not a function`

Comment: Are you returning an array (See the first part of my answer) ? filter is a method for an array. I strongly suggest you not return a string if you are returning multiple values. returning an array makes more sense if you want to return more  items.

Comment: No, it's not array, it is plaintext

Comment: @jesloudr See my updated answer. You can use `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an example, check for `data`'s content - and if it matches your condition (in your case holding "stop") -> `clearInterval()`.

Dummy code:

```
var intervalId = null;
var x = 0;
intervalId = setInterval(crunchifyAjax, 100);

function crunchifyAjax() {
    if (x < 10) {
        x++;
        console.log(x);
        return true;
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId, crunchifyAjax);
}
```